# AWS EKS, How To Hit Pod directly from browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I'm very new to kubernetes. I have spent the last week learning about Nodes, Pods, Clusters, Services, and Deployments.

With that I'm trying to just get some more understanding of how the networking for kubernetes even works. I just want to expose a simple nginx docker webpage and hit it from my browser.

Our VPC is setup with a direct connect so I'm able to hit EC2 instances on their private IP addresses. I also setup the EKS cluster using the UI on aws for now as `private`. For testing purposes I have added my cidr range to be allowed on all TCP as an additional security group in the EKS cluster UI.

Here is my basic service and deployment definitions:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testing-nodeport
  namespace: default
  labels:
    infrastructure: fargate
    app: testing-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: testing-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: testing-port
      protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testing-deployment
  namespace: default
  labels:
    infrastructure: fargate
    app: testing-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      infrastructure: fargate
      app: testing-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        infrastructure: fargate
        app: testing-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - name: testing-port
          containerPort: 80
```

I can see that everything is running correctly when I run:

`kubectl get all -n default`

However, when I try to hit the NodePort IP address on port `80` I can't load it from the browser.

I can hit the pod if I first setup a `kubectl proxy` at the following url (as the proxy is started on port `8001`):

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/testing-nodeport:80/proxy/
```

I'm pretty much lost at this point. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and why I can't hit the basic nginx docker outside of the kubectl proxy command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after 16+ hours of debugging this I finally figured out what's going on. On fargate you can't set the security groups per node like you can with managed node groups. I was setting the security group rules in the "Additional security groups" settings. However, fargate apparently completely ignores those settings and ONLY uses the security group from your "Cluster security group" setting. So in the EKS UI I set the correct rules in the "Cluster security group" and I can now hit my pod directly on a fargate instance.

Big take away from this. Only use "Cluster security group" for fargate nodes.

Answer (score 5):

What if you use the `proxy` option? Something like this:

```sh
kubectl port-forward -n default service/testing-nodeport 3000:80
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:3000 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:3000 -> 80
```

After this, you can access your K8S service from `localhost:3000`. More info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)

Comment: Thanks for responding! The kubectl proxy command will do this automatically for you. Yes I have tried this and it works but I would like to have the ability for other people to just hit it outright with the ip address and port.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that the kubernetes cluster is like your AWS VPC. It has its own internal network with private IPs and connects all the PODs. Kubernetes only exposes things which you explicitly ask to expose.

Service port 80 is available within the cluster. So one pod can talk to this service using the `service name:service port`. But if you need to access from outside, you need `ingress controller / LoadBalancer`. You can also use `NodePort` for testing purposes. The node port will be something bigger than 30000 (within this 30000-32767).

You should be able to access nginx using `node IP:nodeport`. Here I assumed you have security group opening the node port.

---

Use this yaml. I updated the node port to be 31000. You can access the nginx on `nodeport:31000`. As I had mentioned you can not use 80 as it is for within the cluster. If you need to use 80, then you need ingress controller.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testing-nodeport
  namespace: default
  labels:
    infrastructure: fargate
    app: testing-app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: testing-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: testing-port
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: testing-deployment
  namespace: default
  labels:
    infrastructure: fargate
    app: testing-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      infrastructure: fargate
      app: testing-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        infrastructure: fargate
        app: testing-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - name: testing-port
          containerPort: 80
```

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing up above? Am I wrong abou the service type of NodePort that I defined above? Since I didn't define a nodePort in the service defiintion it choses one automatically. I allow ports 0 - 65535 to my network cidr as an additional security group in the EKS UI. Is there a different location I should be adding this or am I defining this incorrectly in the yaml file?

Comment: @wesleywh, You are right on creating the service NodePort. But you are expecting nginx to be available at port 80 outside the cluster. That is not possible. Kubernetes will assign some random ports - if you do not ask for it explicitly - within the given range. Thats what you have to use to access. Not port 80. Run this command `kubectl get all` - check for the port something bigger than 30000. Use that to access your app.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the detailed answer. I will try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: Okay I took your yaml and ran `kubectl apply -f testing.yaml` (saved it to `testing.yaml`). The output said the service updated and the deployment remained unchanged. 

1. I ran `kubectl get all` and got the IP and port (from the NodePort service) and tried that with no luck. 

2. I ran a `kubectl describe <pod>` and got the IP address from there with the port and still no luck. 

3. Finally got the endpont from the service `kubectl describe service testing-nodeport` and that didn't work either.

Final Outputs for everything...
I'm getting a connection timeout for all the above tries.

Comment: Any yes I'm not trying port 80 but port 31000 that is defined in the yaml file.

Comment: Do not use service IP. Use the EC2 instance IP. I assume you have access to the EC2 instance

Comment: I ran `kubectl describe pod <pod>` and got the IP of the instance that way and tried 31000. I also tried port 80 because `kubectl describe service testing-nodeport` showed the following:
`Endpoints:                <POD IP>:80` I also see then when describing the service. Is that bad? `Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP`. Since this is a fargate instance there is no UI to get the underlying EC2 data that I can find other than doing what I did above.

Comment: Looks like there might be issues with actually adding security groups to fargate nodes: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/625